# Asynchronous bidirectional client/server model for WPF->Web

Tags: .net, wpf, asynchronous, websocket, signalr

Ok, I know this might seem like a strange use case, but here goes...

We've got a connectivity-ensured LAN with a large number (30-50 on average) of the same thick-client apps deployed (WPF or possible Windows 8 App, we're not sure yet which of the two our client wants). There will be a central server monitoring these clients for various status updates, some as simple as "are you connected to the network?" and some that involve more complex business rules.

Asynchronous-ness (asynchrony?) is a must, because we need to know of any errors or status updates ASAP. We also need the connection to be bidirectional for obvious reasons.

I'm not here specifically to talk about the architecture, since we're still in discussions on that. But I am wondering if thee is a .NET framework of some kind that allows for the kind of connection we need.

I've looked at [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) and [WebSockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets.websocket.aspx), but both of those seem to cater more towards a web-client with a thick-client back-end, and we need the reverse.

I know this is still sort of vague, and that's mostly because we're still in the design phase. But if anyone has any tips on a framework to look at, that would be most helpful!

Cheers!

Comment: If you have a connectivity-ensured LAN then why are you limiting to websocket?

Comment: Lightstreamer might help you, by using the .NET client library ( http://www.lightstreamer.com )

Comment: SignalR can be hosted in a Console application.  It doesn't have to be hosted in a web application.  SignalR doesn't really care if it's web --> thick-client, thick-client --> web, web --> web, or thick-client --> thick-client.  As long as the server part of SignalR is being hosted somewhere where the clients can connect, it works.

Comment: Eclipsed, I wish you would have posted that as an answer so I could mark it as such. I actually discovered that fact before reading your comment but thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the option to self host in SignalR.
SignalR doesn't care where its hosted.

Taken from the SignalR website:

> A SignalR server is usually hosted in an ASP.NET application in IIS,
>   but it can also be self-hosted (such as in a console application or
>   Windows service) using the self-host library.

**Tutorial: SignalR Self-Host**
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-signalr-self-host